# doctrine2 and codeigniter2, right approach for parent class to interact with child properties

Tags: php, inheritance, properties, parent-child, visibility

I'm searching for this for quite some time now.
I saw few similar questions but not sure if they apply with doctrine2 and this problem.
I'm trying to get started with CodeIgniter2 and Doctrine2, and I'm having some problems, I'm not OOP guru in php.
I would like to have MainObject that will contains methods for CRUD and few others, and I want objects to extend that class and use parent's methods, but with child's properties. Since Doctrine2 uses Private Properties for objects, I cannot access these methods from parent class. For example:

```
   Class MainObject{
    public function validateFields(){
        //go over each field and validate/update if needed
    }
    public function store(){
        // do some validation, some logic, store, etc...
    }
   }
   Class User extends MainObject{
    /**
        * @Column(type="string", length=32, unique=true, nullable=false)
        */
        private $username;

        /**
         * @Column(type="string", length=64, nullable=true)
         */
        private $email;

   }
```

Now, I would like to just call

```
$user = new User();
//set properties, somehow
$user-__set($something);
//call validation or store or some method from the parent that will interact with child properties
$user->validate();
$user->store();
$user->uploadImage();
$user->formatPropertiesForSomethingSpecial();
```

I'm almost there to do this by using the ReflectionClass but I'm not sure that I'm doing this the right way?
Or is there a way to have MainObject with all this methods, and then just pass User to it so it can do what it should do with user, is perhaps that the 'righter' approach? I don't think it will allow me to do something with Private properties from the user, but I guess that User can have its own getters and setters?

I'm working with semi-oop in php for years, but this is something new for me, so thanks for any advice, tutorial, url, critique, anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest (and correct) way is to use a setter.

```
Class User extends MainObject{
    private $username;
    private $email;
    public function set_username($username) {
        $this->username = $username;
    }
}
```

<del>If you want to make it less verbose, use a general purpose setter in the parent:</del>

<del>`Class MainObject{
        public function validateFields(){
        }
        public function store(){
        }
        public function set($data) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                if (property_exists($this, $key)) {
                    $this->$key = $value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // Example
    $user = new User();
    $data = array('username' => 'foo', 'email' => 'bar@bar.bar');
    $user->set($data);
    $user->validate();
    $user->store();`</del>

You will need at least PHP >= 5.1 for the second method.

I just brushed up on my visibility documentation.  You'll need to use a protected property instead of private, or write all of your setters in the child class.

Comment: Thank you sir, this is what I want to use and I'm glad that you understand what I want to do, but this doesn't work due to Private properties, and it causes

Fatal error: Cannot access private property models\User::$username in e:www\application\models\object.php on line 80

Now, this DOES work if I create properties as simple Var like this
Class User extends MainObject{
 var $username;
 var $email;


Now probably the main question is: should I set properties as Public or they MUST be private for doctrine2 to work properly, and for the code to be secure, or whatever might happen?
Thanks!

Comment: Now Protected works as expected, thank you very much! I was under impression that protected is 'stronger' then Private.
I will continue to work with Protected and hope that all will work fine as I planned :)

Comment: The hierarchy of visibility is Private < Protected < Public.  Good luck!